# git error did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, deployment

Running the following command:

```
git push deploy
```

I get this error:

**remote: error: pathspec '"\342\200\223f"' did not match any file(s) known to git.**

Unsure what it means. This is a new repo which pushes a --bare with a hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/srv/project/WEBSITE
export GIT_WORK_TREE
git checkout –f
```

Running Ubuntu Server

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this same error and was able to remove it by changing my post-receive to:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/srv/project/WEBSITE checkout -f
```